# How to choose code font in Android Studio lookup?

Tags: android, android-studio, text, settings, text-size

My text:

[image: My text]

I want text:

[image: I want text]

How can I choose second text?

Comment: goto to file->Settings->Editor->Colors&Fonts->Fonts, and choose ur desired font

Answer (score 0):

> Goto --> File --> Settings --> Search Font --> you will get following
>   page --> change font size(shown below).

[image]